# Force private mode in Everyplay

Tags: unity-game-engine, everyplay

All of uploaded replays is defaultly private. I unchecked Force private mode in Advance setting in my game account, but nothing change. 
Please advice. Is there anything I can do with code in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from https://developers.everyplay.com/faq

"When you share a videos from a development build of your game (build that has not been certified and released on the App Store) you will see a “private mode” option that is marked “on” by default."

Hope this helps!